# Trying to query for customers "company" value in Magento 1.7 DB

Tags: php, mysql, sql, magento

I have been looking around for a solution to this and everything I am finding seems overly complicated for what I am trying to do.

I am trying to get a list of all of my customers that belong in customer group #2. To my knowledge that part works fine.

Next, I am trying to look up their orders and output the names of their companies. Here I think there is an error in my code causing a hang-up.

So the end goal is a list of all company names for customers that belong in group 2.

I am trying to do this via SQL queries. The web page just gets hung up on loading. One time I got it to display some data but it was incomplete.

Below is what I have. Can you please take a look and see what may be wrong? I am hoping there is just an out of place ; or something like that.

*** I did not paste the connection details for security reasons but the code does connect to the DB without issue.**

```
<?php
    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 



//Run a Query to get all wholesale customer IDs

$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM `customer_entity` WHERE `group_id` = 2";
$customerIDs = $conn->query($sql1);


    //so now that we have the wholesale customer IDs we are going to search 
    their orders for their company names.
    while( $row1 = $customerIDs->fetch_assoc() )
    {



        //Run a query to get a list of orders that the customer has placed
        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM `sales_flat_order_address` WHERE 
        `customer_id` = " . $row1["entity_id"] ."";
        $customerOrders = $conn->query($sql2);


        // Echo the orders company name
        while( $row2 = $customerOrders->fetch_assoc() )
        {


            //Check to see if the name is NULL 
            if($row2['company'] !== NULL)
            {
                //display the company name.
                echo $row2['company'] . "</br>";

            }

        }



}

//close the connection
mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> the end goal is a list of all company names for customers that belong in group 2

You could achieve this with a simple `JOIN`ed query. From looking at your code, this should be :

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.company
FROM 
    customer_entity c
    INNER JOIN sales_flat_order_address s ON s.customer_id = c.entity_id
WHERE c.group_id = 2
```

This query will retrieve all users in group 2, then select all their orders, and finally output all (distinct) corresponding companies .

Comment: Thank you so much. I need to study and learn more about JOIN-ed queries. Seems I am overcomplicating things. 

Thank you, thank you, thank you, thank you.